# Teshuva for uttering the ineffable name?

Tags: halacha, repentance-teshuvah

Is there any or a specific way to repent for uttering the ineffable name?

Comment: Yes, the same as any other sin.  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62044/teshuva-for-wasting-seed?rq=1#comment170555_62044

Comment: @Heshy That's fundamentally true, but there's sufficient reason to think repentance for this sin at least merits its own specific discussion ([*Sh'mos* 20:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#6), Ramban ad loc. sv. "ועל דרך הפשט", *'Avoda Zara* 17b-18a "והתנן אלו שאין להם חלק לעולם הבא... אבא שאול אומר אף ההוגה את השם באותיותיו להתלמד עבד כדתניא לא תלמד לעשות אבל אתה למד להבין ולהורות אלא מאי טעמא אענש משום הוגה את השם בפרהסיא", Tosefta 7:2 "כל עברות שבתורה כתוב בהן ונקה וזו כתוב בה לא ינקה", though this Tosefta might be limited to false oaths, see also *T'mura* 3b-4a, *Yoma* 85b-86a).

Comment: If the name is ineffable how did you utter it?